# HTML codes refernce tag

Tags: button, submit

I want to create a html page, where the data given in the submit button should automatically?
go the other buttons ..for example :
If i enter america in the submit button ; 
below that i want a google button where the value "America" should go directly to the google button so when the user clicks google button the search result for america should be displayed.
Ex : https://www.google.co.in/?gws_rd=cr&ei=vTtxUpqDGM3arAf-rYHoAw#q=america ;

The submit button text should be placed after the "=" in the google link

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear, but i guess this is what you want ...

```
<form action="http://www.google.com/search" method="get">
    Google Search: <input type="text" name="q" />
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```